# The foreground color changes after `ls` command

Tags: command-line, bash, colors, ls

I change shell's foreground color with `echo -ne '\e[1;31m'` command but when I execute `ls` command the foreground color reverts back to the original previous color. This weird behavior doesn't occur when other commands are executed. I am clueless about the cause behind this.

Please write an explanation for this and also suggest the remedy. thanks

I am using **UBUNTU 14.10**.

**EDIT-** I have tried to remove the escape sequence for white color foreground by setting the alias for `ls` as:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto |sed -r 's/\x1b[37m]//''
```

But, this has a problem too, the `ls` outputs all the directory names and filenames with single color ,i.e not with the default colors for all items.This is strange as I have removed just the `[37m` which is the white foreground but it removes all the colors.

Comment: Could it be something to do with there being a predefined alias for `ls` which is `ls --colour=auto`? There's also an alias for grep with an auto colour option, so maybe grep would exhibit the same behaviour. You could always try unsetting the ls alias to see if it helps.

Comment: @Arronical Thanks for the quick reply. Actually commenting out the `ls --color=auto` line does it but it removes the actual colored output of ls command . `ls` outputs the directory name and file name all with the same color .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE-** As waltinator says executing `bash` command right after `ls` command will create child shell which will probably eat up resources , I had to look for another solution. I tried executing `echo -ne '\e[1;31m'` light after ls command therefore I put it in the `bls` funciton.

I somehow reached to my own solution to this problem. The suggestions by meuh and waltinator were to look for escape sequences sent by `ls` command and I even found out those. I tried to remove escape sequence by using `sed` but due to my inexperience at this I was not able to use it perfectly perhaps.

Later,I noticed that executing `bash` after ls command reverts the foreground back to the color I wanted.`I decided against using bash after ls`

Meanwhile , I found a way as :

1. First of all I put the command `echo -ne '\e[0;31m'` in a shell script and add the shell script to `.bashrc`.
2. Second, I defined a function so that `bash` would be executed right after `ls` as :

> bls( ) {
>
> ```
>  ls "$@" && echo -ne '\e[1;31m';
>  }
> ```

3. I exported the above function as :

   `export -f bls`

So, Now I have to do a `bls` for listing directories and not changing the foreground color. This didn't actually solve the `ls` problem but it did find me another way. I just have to type one more letter in `bls`

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. The `bash` commands spawns another shell process as a child of the current one. It takes over STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, and reads the startup files (see `man bash`). To see your problem, type `ps -fu $USER` and look at all the `bash` processes. You will eventually exhaust some resource and be unhappy.

Comment: Could you add the results of `alias ls;env | egrep '^LS_' ; echo "$PS1" | od -bc` to your question?

Comment: `LS_COLORS=fi=01;32:di=01;34:ln=00;38:*.txt=01;37:*.tgz=01;31:*.zip=00;33:*.z=01;36:*.html=00;32:*.png=01;35:*.deb=00;35:*.sh=01;31:*..sh=01;31:
0000000 133 134 165 100 134 150 072 040 134 100 040 134 167 135 040 110
          [   \   u   @   \   h   :       \   @       \   w   ]       H
0000020 165 153 165 155 040 155 145 162 145 040 141 153 141 134 044 040
          u   k   u   m       m   e   r   e       a   k   a   \   $    
0000040 012
         \n
0000041`

Comment: This is the output of the above command , I am not adept at shell scripting , unix and linux , most of the things I do just by looking others.I would welcome suggestions from you on how to become an expert at this. I knew that this is not a solution of the real problem just an other way around.

Comment: @waltinator Please take the downvote back if you think that my updated solution won't cause any problem and I would appreciate if you add a solution as an answer I would accept that . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Commands which set colours may finish by sending the sequence `ESC [ 0 m` to reset the current attributes for the terminal.  The easiest thing for you to do is change your shell prompt to always set the colour back to what you want.

Add to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PS1='\e[1;31m'"$PS1"
```

Comment: The export you suggested , will it set the color of the prompt or of the whole foreground ? I mean the text color like the color when I type .

Comment: I copied your own chosen escape sequence, which is the text foreground.

Comment: That's the color code . Setting PS1 actually sets the prompt color only IMO. It doesn't change the foreground color. I tried the above export but it didn't work.

Comment: If you do `script foo.txt`, from there until you type `exit`, all I/O will be captured in `foo,txt`. Examine it with `od -bc foo.txt` and   look at the ESCape sequences.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks I tried the steps you told me to but please pardon my inability to read that file I just cannot figure out which escape sequences are causing it . A little more insight would be helpful :)

Comment: @rohitsrivastava I forgot to say you need to re-login to have the change take effect. Or to try it out in the terminal, simply type the same line as a command.

Comment: @waltinator Upon reading foo.txt I could figure the sequence `[ 0 m`  is causing this to happen . How can I remove this sequences , will removing the sequence help?

Comment: `man console_codes` will help. The only suggestion I have for eliminating the suspect sequence  is to start with the end of output (in the foo.txt file) and understand each ESCape sequence, and how it got produced. When you find that you have understood how the sequence you want to eliminate was produced, fix that part.

Comment: @waltinator hi , `[0m` is the escape sequence executed by `ls` command `0m` is the code for resetting all the attributes to default which sets the foreground to white , How can I make sure that `ls` command doesn't execute that sequence?

Comment: @meuh hi , `[0m` is the escape sequence executed by `ls` command `0m` is the code for resetting all the attributes to default which sets the foreground to white , How can I make sure that `ls` command doesn't execute that sequence? Your suggested export doesn't work. thanks

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem. How did you do that? =)

Comment: Read `man bash`, the section on "PROMPTING", and read `man console_codes`.  Let's take `ls` out of the equation. Do the `script/od -bc` thing with `echo "my output ends after this LF"` replacing the `ls`.  The `od -bc` output should show "L" "F" "a linefeed character" and that is all the `echo` outputs. Subsequent characters come from your prompt.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you  so much for your time and support . I have found my own solution which I am going to post as an answer but your suggestions enhanced my knowledge . :)